# php find group in array with nearly same string

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array with upto 15k Entrys, the array lookis like this

```
$data = array(
    array('city' => 'berlin'),
    array('city' => 'siegen'),
    array('city' => 'Siegen'),
    array('city' => 'berlin-ost'),
    array('city' => 'Berlin kreutzbreg'),
    array('city' => 'Hagen'),
    array('city' => 'Bonn'),
    array('city' => 'Olpe')
)
```

now i want to find all grous in the array, but i my code take to much time

```
//this is a short versiono f the code
$group = null
foreach($data as $d){
    $str = strtolower($d['city']);
    $worked = false;
    foreach($group as $g){
        $t1 = $g == $str;
        $t2 =levenshtein($g,$str);
        if($t1 ||$t2/strlen($str) < 0.25)  {
            // add $d too group, removed for example
            $worked = true;
            continue;
        }
    if(!$worked){
        $group[$str] = $d;
    }
}
return $group
```

is ther a faster way that do not need so much loops? or faster checking methods

this could bee the result:

```
$data = array(
    berlin => array('city' => 'berlin'),
    siegen => array('city' => 'siegen'),
    hagen =>array('city' => 'Hagen'),
    bonn => array('city' => 'Bonn'),
    olpe => array('city' => 'Olpe')
)
```

Comment: That's not working code.  `$group` will always be `null`, and what should the result look like???

Comment: The inner loop should be `foreach($data as $g)`

Comment: You need to initialize `$group` to an empty array so you can add to it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver this is a shreend variant of the code, and not tested. i insert to groups at the commentar,@Barmar the looping is good, $group is smaler area

Comment: Matching with `levenshtein` like that will never give perfect results. For instance:  `levenshtein('Altenburg','Altenberg')/strlen('Altenberg') < 0.25`, but they are different cities. The contrary happens with `levenshtein('Gießen','Giessen)')/strlen('Giessen') > 0.25` -- same city.

Comment: I would suggest to load an official list of cities into `$group` first, and then read your data. For each item check `isset($group[$str])`, and if so, maybe increase a counter or so. Only otherwise, go through `$group` and choose the entry with the best match (not `< 0.25`, just best).

Comment: @trincot this is an good Idee, i will test this.